# template query, accessing private member

Tags: c++, templates

I am referring to one of the exercises mentioned in the book "thinking in c++.
Below code snippet throws an error for the call h.play, which i understand,  because
the member i is private. But I was expecting the same error for the call me.play. If i comment the call h.play the code compiles fine. Why there is no error for the call me.play ?

```
class Buddy {};

template<class T> class My {
  int i;
public:
  void play(My<Buddy>& s) {
    s.i = 3;
  }
};

int main() {
  My<int> h;
  My<Buddy> me, bud;
  h.play(bud);
  me.play(bud);
}
```

Thankyou.

[Edit] Is there a way to see what code the compiler has generated for

```
My<int> h and 
My<Buddy> me
```

? (anything similar to -E compiler flag) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members are always "public" to instances of another object with the same type.

Meaning a `My<Buddy>` instance (such as `me`) can access private members of another `My<Buddy>` instance (such as `bud`).

Keep in mind that `My<int>` is a completely different type than `My<Buddy>`, and so it cannot access those members.

Comment: Thankyou. Is there a way to see the code generated by compiler for the template instances ?

Comment: @irappa Unfortunately, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `play` method is defined as taking a reference to `My<Buddy>` rather than a `My<T>`, the effective class is the same type when called on another instance of `My<Buddy>`. Therefore private members are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in languages that just pretend to have strong static type system and generics (looking at you Java), C++ allows you to disambiguate statically parametric types (template types) based on the parameters (the parameters being usually types) the types are templated on.

*Note*: You can also use a derived (dynamically / late bound) type as a parameter for a statically parametrized type, but it's not relevant in this scenario.

In other words, in C++:

- `typeid(me) == typeid(bud)` will be **TRUE**
- `typeid(h) == typeid(me)` will be **FALSE**

even though the type "My" is the same.

You can access the private data-members from **the same**  type as though they were public, but as you can see, the second comparison is false because the operands are **not** of the same type, therefore you violate the access restrictions of the type.

Also, I don't think there is any way to take a look at the compiler-generated code. (As far as I know.)